# Detox: How to bypass authentication when testing

Tags: react-native, detox

I have an app that uses `OAuth`. I don't want to have to use an external, unmocked server to be able to log in. Is there a way of bypassing the authentication on detox-tested applications?

Something such as: A GoTo navigational screen detox method, or a testing-only dark launched button that will navigate to the home screen.

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Classic problem. Perhaps you can launch the app in an environment signaling it to behave as if already logged in. Or a deep-link to the screen you want to test. I've also had luck with invisible touchable areas.

Answer (score 1):

The way we solved this, was by creating a mock server, implementing there a very simple OAuth and point the app there.

Another way is to create a specific implementation on the app to open directly certain page (for instance with specific test deep linking).

Answer (score -2):

Just login inside before or befoleAll (if you use jest) setup method.

Comment: The question asks how to log in. This answer doesn't address that.